# Auto resize font size of component in sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch

In my app font-size of component remain same for all screen size of mobile,tablet,browser.
i have try to use em but not helpful.
can any one help me.
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found solution :
Add vh or vw in font size property.